# Accessing variables of parent function in Javascript event handlers

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, dom-events

I have an event handler which is bound to a 'change' event.  The problem is, functions within that function cannot access any elements of the parent function

```
Process.prototype.handleCheckboxChange = function(event) {
    var rgbs = []
    $(':checked').each(function(index,element) {
       var color = [0,3,4];
       rgbs.push(color);
    })
}
```

I have been reading all around the place about closures, but everything I have seen seems to indicate that an inner function should be able to access its parents local variables, whereas this is not the case here: `rgbs` is undefined.

It may be of use to know that when binding (with jQuery's `bind()`) I am using closures to set the this keyword to the original object (in a way I don't really understand), although the problem was the same when I was not doing this:

```
Process.prototype.doBinding = function() {
   $('checkbox').bind('change', function(event) {self.handleCheckboxChange(event)})
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and  how I can access rgbs?

Comment: `rgbs` seems a private variable inside the function - where are you trying to access it?

Comment: This should work (apart from that the first snippet is not valid JavaScript and that you didn't define `self` in the second one). `rgbs` is visible inside the `each` callback. Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Are you sure `handleCheckboxChange` is even executed?

Comment: Thanks, indeed it is working.  I actually simplified what I was doing here (and ended up masking the problem).  The problem was simply that if you don't actually use a variable (in this case rgbs) within the inner function, then in the Google Chrome debugger at least, if you try to reference it it tells you it is undefined.  I am not sure why it does this, but the moral of the story it seesm is don't rely on the debugger to tell you whether a variable is defined, and don't over simplify examples for stackoverflow!