# Accessing parent members from javascript functions called by event handlers

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

**The question**

In Javascript, how can an event handler function refer to members of its parent? i.e. can you define an event handler function part of a larger object and have that function "know about" its parent?

(Note that someone else posted a nearly identical question [Accessing variables of parent function in Javascript event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490778/accessing-variables-of-parent-function-in-javascript-event-handlers) . It hadn't been answered. Hence the repost )

**Erroneous Presuppositions**

I had thought that at "function definition" time you could capture a copy of "this" for later re-use, (e.g. copy to "self"). Evidently I was wrong: after I bind the function to the event ("click()" below), "self" subsequently refers to the html anchor tag ('');

The general context :
trying to use encapsuation/object-orientedness  for code-re-use in javascript.

**Example**

Here's a simple example (cribbed from elsewhere and modified).

The function succeeds when called during page load, but fails when the user preses "click"

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" rel="my link">MY LINK</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

var Construct = function() {
    var self = this;    

    this.attr1 = 3;
    this.attr2 = 2;
    this.childObj = {
        method1: function () {
            // this function fails if called from an event handler
            // edited this function to "do something", i.e. provide a visual cue upon execute
            var foo = self.attr1 * self.attr2;
            alert ('value is ' + foo);
            return foo;
        }
    }
}

     var obj = new Construct();
    
    // this call succeeds
    alert (obj.childObj.method1());   

    //this call fails as soon as the event handler refers to "self"
    $("#myLink").click(obj.childObj.method1);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update/Edit**
-Updated the example to give a 'visual cue' when it runs
-added this section.

My error. As pointed out below, the example works fine.  My original, non-working code used this:

```
   this.self = this
```

instead of

```
   var self = this
```

I didn't realize the distinction (in Java they would be identical) and missed the fact that my example actually worked, (whereas my code failed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. `self` refers to the object as it is supposed to. That's how the lexical scoping of javascript is defined.

The problem is your handler does nothing. `method1` simply returns `6` but you never tell it do anything with that value. If you want to prove it to yourself, the line before the return, add an alert: `alert(self.attr1 * self.attr2);`

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5LK75/)**

Comment: I wanted to prove this for myself.  It does appear to work.  Code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sPpsG/.

Comment: What threw me off on this one is that the `this` value when `method1()` is called from the event handler is the `this` of the object that caused the event.  It is not the "this" of the actual `obj`.  But, the code works because the object doesn't use the `this` value passed in, it uses the `self` value that it saved earlier.  At first I thought it wouldn't work, then I found out it would work and I wanted to understand why.

Comment: OK. My bad in posting the question. In my original code, I had used " this.self = this"    instead of "var self = this". In java, the two are interchangeable; in javascript evidently not.  I didn't realize the difference between the original and the example.